# How to use make it where you only take the first three argc and ignore the rest

Tags: c, argc

So I am working on a project and we take in input with `argc`. So what is happening is that we need to have a total of 5 `argc` in one of the methods and in the second method we need only 3 `argc`. So I tested it out and noticed if I change the checker from `!=5` to `!=3` it works for the method that uses 3 `argc` but not the one that uses 5 `argc`. Is there a way that lets me use both method?

```
int moveFile(struct filesystem_volume volume, struct arguments command) {

    /* Checking argc */
    if(command.argc < 5) {
        printf("\t***ERROR - TOO FEW ARGS***\n");
        return 0; // check
    }
    else if(command.argc > 5){
        printf("\t***ERROR - TOO MANY ARGS***\n");
        return 0; //check
    }

    /* copy file */
    strcpy(command.args[0], "cp");
    if (copyFile(volume, command) == 0) {
        printf("\t***ERROR - COPYING FILE***\n");
        return 0;
    }     

    /* remove file */
    strcpy(command.args[0], "rm");
    command.argc = 3;
    if (removeFile(volume, command) == 0) {
        printf("\t***ERROR - REMOVING FILE***\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here's the code but I don't think you would need code

Comment: And why not just check `if (argc == 5)` ???

Comment: I'm supposing that the validation is for the "move file" action? An action which does the two separate actions of "copy" and "delete"? Then your validation should be for the "move file" action *only* (IMO), and then you create separate `command` structures for the separate sub-actions needed, without any validation in the `moveFile` function (they are instead in their respective `copyFile` and `removeFile` functions).

Comment: Ok i found the issue it was with my virtual machine it worked for my partners device.